# Return value after handler ends

Tags: java, gwt

I have problem with return value from my method. I created an `Image` and I want scale it and return.

```
final Image img = new Image(src);

img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent arg0) {
    resize img...
    }
}

return img;
```

How do I return it after I have changed its size?

Comment: Put whatever you want to do after resizing in the `onLoad` function after resize. There is no such a thing of returning a value from handler.

Comment: If I put return after onLoad I get img with default heigh and width.

Comment: Use a callback to return the value (something similar to the GWT RPC mechanism).

Comment: Can you add more code of what you want to do? maybe we can help more that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need not return the `image` just to re-size.

The  `Image` should  be added to the `DOM` first.Then you can do operations on that .

You can do something like this :

```
Image image = new Image();
        image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                // resize image
                image.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Style.Visibility.Visible); 
            } 


        });

image.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Style.Visibility.HIDDEN); 
RootPanel.get().add(image);
image.setUrl(url);
```

Comment: Even when I do like this parent will resize to img default size but i don't have any other idea. Thanks for your help.